# Фонемы в русском языке

Tags: фонология

Запутался с выделением фонем.
Есть такие слова: ***дом-том-лом*** (в них видим фонемы **/д/; /т/; /л/**, т.к. звуки различают смысл, хотя стоят они в одинаковой позиции)

---

А что насчет, например, ***"рот" и "род"***? Здесь тоже будут разные фонемы или же в данном случае уже можно увидеть варианты одной фонемы:
**рот [рот]** - фонемы /т/, потому что **"рта"**? **Род [рот]** - фонема "д", потому что **"рода"**.
Тот же ответ хотелось бы получить и относительно гласных:
**"вал"** и **"вял"** - [в а л] и [в' а л]. Тоже здесь разные фонемы - **/а/ и /'а/**, например, или это варианты одной фонемы [а]? Будут ли тогда [**в] и [в']** разными фонемами, раз они различают слова?

Comment: Скажите, у вас школьная или вузовская программа? Вам нужно задание выполнить или для себя эту тему понять?  Просто разные могут быть ответы. Кроме того, существуют две фонологические школы с разным пониманием фонемы.

Comment: @Sharon Я занимаюсь с ребенком, который изучает русский язык углубленно (профиль такой). Фонологию я изучал еще в вузе, но уже забыл, т.к. нет нужды вспоминать о фонемах, когда всегда разбираю звуки с детьми. Дети не будут делать разборы по МФШ или СФШ, однако (согласно кодификатору) разницу между звуком и фонемой они должны знать и уметь показывать это различие на конкретных примерах.

Comment: Понятно, это уже сложнее. Дело в том, что в вузах предпочитают МФШ, что и понятно. В этом случае буквенный состав морфемы совпадает с ее фонемным составом, тут и думать особенно нечего: в слове  «род» фонема Д. Казалось бы,  и в школах должны бы придерживаться хотя бы принципов МФШ, но я в этом не уверена. Такое впечатление, что там СФШ или вообще не пойми что, судя по тому, как в обычных школах дети  делают фонетический разбор. Или мне так показалось...

Comment: А вот в СФШ  морфемный состав не соответствует фонемному,  и там вполне могут считать, что в слове «род» фонема Т (то, что слышится). А что в вашей школе, трудно предположить.

Comment: @Sharon про то, что фонематический разбор делается с опорой на морфемный (если по МФШ), я знаю. Непонятно другое: варианты одной фонемы и разные фонемы. Можете, пожалуйста, на моих примерах это показать (если берем МФШ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представители Московской фонологической школы считают фонему **функциональной** единицей. МФШ  опирается на положение о неизменности фонематического состава морфемы.

В словах **РОД и РОТ** в слабой позиции слышится звук Т, изменяем позицию, ставим звук перед гласной: РОДА и РТА. Согласный звук в сильной позиции перед гласной является фонемой. Значит, в слове РОД фонема Д, в слове РОТ – фонема Т. Таким образом, проверили звук, определили фонемный состав слова, обозначили соответствующими буквами. Это смысл проверки.

**ВАЛ и ВЯЛ**, позиция гласного сильная (ударная), проверка не требуется, это одна фонема [а], представленная вариантами /а/ и /'а/. Звук В (мягкий или твердый) в сильной позиции (перед гласной), это разные фонемы [в] и [в'], что определяется на слух, эти согласные фонемы и различают слова.

**Главный принцип**: звук в сильной позиции является фонемой и определяется на слух; звук в слабой позиции нужно проверить.

Comment: Интересно всё это, но непонятно для дилетанта. Как можно выделять фонему Д в слове РОД, если само понятие фонемы подразумевает звук? Плюс, если что, от меня :))

Comment: Тогда вас надо в СФШ определить. Теперь мне понятно, почему это направление  существует вообще, да еще оказывает влияние на современную школу :)) Это консерваторы  стремятся как-то скрыть великое открытие Бодуэн де Куртенэ, сделанное более 100 лет назад! Это наше естественное мышление тормозит науку!))

Comment: Раньше считали, что звук – это только  фонетика, но вот была открыта  его функциональная природа.   Среди всех звуков  в речи были выделены звуки с особым статусом – смысловые звуки (их называют смыслоразличительными).  В слове РОД фонема Д отвечает за смысл этого слова, а Т – это всего лишь уступка нашему желанию не выговаривать все звуки ясно (авось и так поймут)…

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
  А с ВАРИАНТАМИ гласных фонем в РАД – РЯД вообще прикольная история получилась. Если заинтересуетесь темой, можно потом как-нибудь обсудить…

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пока не пойду в школу тёмного леса... :)  А прикольную историю услышать можно!

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Что школа! Мой интерес к РЯ начался с фонемы, просто я однажды прочитала книжку "Дважды два не равно четырем", там даже математика для младших классов рассматривалась с этой точки зрения. С тех пор и определилось направление моего мышления в целом...)) А прикольную историю вы не оцените, пока не «втянитесь» в тему.